# Laravel, how cast object to new Eloquent Model?

Tags: laravel, post, eloquent

I get via Request a Json Object.
I clearly parse this object in order to check if it may fit the destination model.

Instead of assigning property by property. Is there a quick way to populate the model with the incoming object?

Comment: I like all answers I'm puzzled about what to accept as "TheAnswer" since everyone is adding something interesting. :)

Comment: I guess you gotta wait for someone to sum it all up into "The Answer" ;) Or..  write it yourself!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have an array of arrays, then you can use the `hydrate()` method to cast it to a collection of the specified model:

```php
$records = json_decode($apiResult, true);

SomeModel::hydrate($records);
```

If you just have a single record, then you can just pass that array to the model’s constructor:

```php
$model = new SomeModel($record);
```

Comment: OMG!  hydrate just saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Just pass your object casted to array as Model constructor argument

```
$model = new Model((array) $object);
```

Internally this uses `fill()` method, so you may first need to add incoming  attributes to `$fillable` property or first create model and then use `forceFill()`.

Comment: Testing the the case on laravel 5.5. There's no need to add attributes to $fillable.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert that object to array and use `fill($attributes)` method.

As method name says, it will fill object with provided values. Keep in mind that it will not persist to database, You have to fire `save()` method after that.
Or if You want to fill and persist in one method - there is `create($attributes)` which runs `fill($attributes)` and `save()` under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mass Assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature of Laravel,

You model would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'phone'];
}
```

And the process of populating the Model would be like this:

```
// This would be your received json data converted to array
// use 'json_decode($json, true)' to convert json data to array
$json_arr = [
    'name' => 'User Name',
    'email' => 'email@example.com',
    'phone' => '9999999999'
];
$user = new \App\User($json_arr);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but, create will actually save a record in my database driver engine.

Comment: @koalaok Yup, you're correct, it can be done by using `new` keyword like this - `new \App\User($json_arr);` I've updated the answer, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Castings may fail due to several reasons. A safe way is to add a static function to the model to generate from both array or object. feels like an extension to the model.

```
public static function generateFromObject($object)
    {
        $myModel = new MyModel();
        foreach($object as $k => $v) 
            $myModel->{$k} = $v; //for arrays $myModel[$k] = $v;
        return $myModel;
    }
```

and you can use anywhere like,

```
$myModel = MyModel::generateFromObject($myObjectOrArray)->save();
```